# Push array into JSON but got unwanted result

Tags: php, arrays, json

I suck at formatting, maybe I had a bad foundation. I have a json like this

```
'first_name'=>'steve', 'msg'=>'something here','profile_id'=>1
```

and I want to push a new item into it, I wrote

```
$i = array('first_name'=>'steve', 'msg'=>'something here','profile_id'=>1);
$loginId = array($_GET['login_id']);
array_push($i,$loginId);

echo json_encode($i);
```

The result I got is strange:

[image]

Comment: whats the value of `$loginId` ?

Comment: @Vainglory07 steve_job

Comment: then what do you want to do with that? just put it inside the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = array('first_name'=>'steve', 'msg'=>'something here','profile_id'=>1);
$loginId = $_GET['login_id'];

$i['login_id']=$loginId;    
echo json_encode($i);
```

The reason array_push didn't work is because you are treating $i as an array (collection) of objects (arrays), while it is just a key-value list (map).

If the array is like K1=>V1, K2=>V2, use $arr[K3]=V3 to add another pair.

If the array is like [(k1,v1), (k2,v2)], then array_push($arr,(k3,v3));

Comment: In the future, use print_r to debug the raw array instead of encoding in JSON.

Comment: @user3318525 Does it matter where in the array it is? I am pretty sure it makes no difference.

Comment: @user3318525 It's an associative array, you shouldn't care about element order as you would typically be accessing the array elements by key.

Comment: The order of keys should not matter. You never have to access the array (a "map" to be precise) linearly.

Comment: If you are iterating through the JSON encoded array and print out each pair, and that you'd like the keys to show in specific order, make sure the PHP array is in the right order first. For this, you'll need another array so that you can assign an OrderIndex to each key, then use usort to sort the original array based on these keys. Or... you can declare the first key pair the first, since you already know which keys are there.

Comment: If you insist on putting the `login_id` in front, assign that to a temporary variable and then use [`array_unshift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to prepend.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically taking a value `$_GET['login_id']`, placing it in an array and trying to push it into an associate array, so you you get a new numeric index `0` holding a nested array, which in turn holds your value.

If you want the entire thing to be treated uniformly as an associative array (or an object once converted to JSON) then you should do something like:

```
$i = array('first_name'=>'steve', 'msg'=>'something here','profile_id'=>1);
$i['login_id'] = $_GET['login_id'];
echo json_encode($i);
```